# How to call a procedure if the procedure does not have parameter

Tags: asp.net

```
create proc sp_dropdown

as
begin

SELECT r1.regid, r.registration
FROM table1 as r1
INNER JOIN table2 as r  ON r1.regid=r.registration and r1.status=r.status
end
```

Comment: Just as one that does have parameters, but without the parameters. Read [ask] and share your research.

Answer (score 0):

this above class is my sp return type,

```
public class GetAllTableNames_Result
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and i can call this like

```
 public List<GetAllTableNames_Result> GetTableNames()
    {
        List<GetAllTableNames_Result> gatnr = new List<GetAllTableNames_Result>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "GetAllTableNames", _connection) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};
        try
        {
            _connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                  //do something with  data 
                gatnr.Add(new GetAllTableNames_Result()
                {
                    Name = rdr[0].ToString()
                });

            }
            _connection.Close();

            return gatnr;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

i believe you can get point